# Como alocar a memória de programa e armazenamento antes de executar minha aplicação no WinCE?

Tags: c#, memória, alocação, windows-ce

Estou reprogramando uma aplicação em C# para rodar no Windows CE, Porém, minha máquina tem pouca memória.
Por isso, preciso alocar a quantidade adequada de memória de processamento (program memory) e de armazenamento (storage memory).  Não posso alocar isso manualmente a cada reinicialização, então encontrei a função **SetSystemMemoryDivision()**.
O código para alocar a memória é basicamente o seguinte:

```
        //Confere se a memória está alocada corretamente
        while (storage_page != 800)
        {
            //Seta a memória para 800 pages de 4096 bytes cada (4Kb * 800 = 3.200Kb)
            storage_page = 800;

            //Grava a memória setada
            SetSystemMemoryDivision(storage_page);

            Thread.Sleep(200);

            //Lê a memória do sistema
            GetSystemMemoryDivision(ref storage_page, ref ram_page, ref page_size);
        }
        chamamenu();
```

A função está funcionando em modo debug, mas sempre que reinicio a máquina e tento rodar o programa, o sistema trava.

Como posso garantir que a memória foi alocada antes de rodar qualquer outro processo que possa travar a máquina? É possível que a aplicação esteja alocando mais do que os 32mB disponíveis para RAM.

Comment: No [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886822.aspx) diz que essa função foi "deprecated" e que não deve ser usada.

Comment: Obrigado, dcastro.  
Infelizmente o Windows CE todo é obsoleto, mas ainda é o ambiente padrão para esta aplicação.  
Alguma função substituiu a antiga ou a Microsoft simplesmente acha que não precisamos mais gerenciar as memórias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema resolvido.

O principal problema era com o GC do CF 2.0, que não estava conseguindo gerenciar a coleta corretamente.
Com uma atualização do .NET CF v2.0 para v3.5 tanto na máquina quanto no projeto, o GC começou a gerenciar corretamente a coleta e a aplicação funcionou perfeitamente.

Obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar e espero que eu tenha ajudado alguém com problemas semelhantes.

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço muito quanto ao Windows CE, mas caso precise de uma maior quantidade de memória, utilize a memória virtual.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Se usando as importações prontas do .NET não funcionar, utilize P/Invoke.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79069/How-to-use-a-memory-mapped-file-with-Csharp-in-Win

Comment: Infelizmente não posso usar a primeira opção, pois o WinCE 5.0 ainda usa o .NET CF 2.0. Mas a segunda opção me pareceu bastante interessante. O maior problema para implementá-la é que não sei o tamanho da alocação (MapSize) que tenho que fazer, já que o consumo de memória se dá pela criação de instâncias dos formulários.

Comment: Se possível, use Structs e a classe Marshal para pegar os tamanhos.